# How to find a last occurrence of set of characters in string using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I need find the last index of set of characters in a string. Consider the set of characters be **x,y,z** and string as **Vereador Luiz Pauly Home** then I need index as **18**.

So for finding the index I have created a pattern with **DOTALL** flag and **greedy quantifier** as **(?s).*(x|y|z)**. When the pattern is applied to that string(multiline), I can find out index from the start group. The code:

```java
int findIndex(String str){
  int index = -1;
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s).*(x|y|z)");
  Matcher m = regex.matcher(str);
  if(m.find()){
    index = m.start(1);
  }
  return index;
}
```

As expected it is returning the values correctly, if there is match.

> But if there is no match, then it takes too long time *(17 minutes for 600000 characters)* as it is a Greedy match.

I tried with other quantifiers, but can't get the desired output. **So can anyone refer any better regex?**

PS: I can also think about traversing the content from last and finding the index.But I hope there is some better way in regex which can do the job quickly.

Comment: Why not just remove the `.*`, and change that `if` to `while`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure three "lastIndexOf" and comparing the results is faster than any RegEx

Comment: Try `"([xyz])(?=[^xyz]*$)"`. `.*` used at the start always causes much backtracking.

Comment: Do you **have** to use regex?

Comment: Seems a solution.Will try it. Thanks @AndyTurner

Comment: @Smutje but you loose the power of regex, based on the need, this might be complicate to implement.

Comment: The need is being described above, it is to find the last position of one of three characters in a string.

Comment: I just tried this, generating a 600k-long string, using your regex, and it completed really quickly.

Comment: I agree @smutje, for this specific pattern. But imagine in two months, some end up here searching how to find the last match of a complex regex. If all he can find for an answer is to use "lastIndexOf", it won't help him. I always try to see the big picture, simply because I find myself in that case, remember that we ask for MCVE, so a complex problem should be simplified at the most to be put in a question. Well, that how I see this, just my opinion ;)

Comment: Sure, and if anyone searches for a "last occurrence of" solution they find full-blown RegEx complexity and c&p them not understanding that they summon a whole new degree of complication and errors. Fantasizing about potential problems should be kept out of StackOverflow for obvious reasons.

Comment: Try also `^(?:[^xyz]*+([xyz]))+`, it seems the fastest from what I tried.

Comment: Could you please let know what you chose in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways to solve the problem and the best way will depend on the size of the input and the complexity of the pattern:

1. Reverse the input string and possibly the pattern, this might work for non-complex patterns. Unfortunately `java.util.regex` doesn't allow to to match the pattern from right to left.
2. Instead of using a greedy quantifier simply match the pattern and loop `Matcher.find()` until last occurrence is found.
3. Use a different regex engine with better performance e.g. [RE2/J: linear time regular expression matching in Java](https://github.com/google/re2j).

If option 2 is not efficient enough for your case I'd suggest to try RE2/J:

> Java's standard regular expression package, java.util.regex, and many other widely used regular expression packages such as PCRE, Perl and Python use a backtracking implementation strategy: when a pattern presents two alternatives such as `a|b`, the engine will try to match subpattern `a` first, and if that yields no match, it will reset the input stream and try to match `b` instead.
>
> If such choices are deeply nested, this strategy requires an exponential number of passes over the input data before it can detect whether the input matches. If the input is large, it is easy to construct a pattern whose running time would exceed the lifetime of the universe. This creates a security risk when accepting regular expression patterns from untrusted sources, such as users of a web application.
>
> In contrast, the RE2 algorithm explores all matches simultaneously in a single pass over the input data by using a nondeterministic finite automaton.

Answer (score 3):

Performance issues with the `(?s).*(x|y|z)` regex come from the fact the `.*` pattern is the first subpattern that grabs the whole string first, and then backtracking occurs to find `x`, `y` or `z`. If there is no match, or the match is at the start of the string, and the strings is very large, this might take a really long time.

The `([xyz])(?=[^xyz]*$)` pattern seems a little bit better: it captures `x`, `y` or `z` and asserts there is no other `x`, `y` or `z` up to the end of the string, but it also is somewhat resource-consuming due to each lookahead check after a match is found.

The fastest regex to get your job done is

```
^(?:[^xyz]*+([xyz]))+
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^xyz]*+([xyz]))+` - 1 or more repetitions of

  - `[^xyz]*+` - any 0 or more chars other than `x`, `y` and `z` matched possessively (no backtracking into the pattern is allowed)
  - `([xyz])` - Group 1: `x`, `y` or `z`.

The Group 1 value and data will belong to the last iteration of the repeated group (as all the preceding data is re-written with each subsequent iteration).

Comment: @user7294900 It is not necessary if the `if` block is used, but it just explicitly tells us we are searching right from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder both has a `reverse` and is a CharSequence, so searching is possible.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[xyz]");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();
Matcher m = p.matcher(sb);
return m.find() ? sb.length() - m.end() : -1;
```

Unfortunately reversal is costly.

A solution without regex is probably faster.

(BTW surrogate pairs are handled correctly by the reversal.)